# Is there any website for peer reviewing english

Tags: discussion

> I am *Name* welcome to yourmathtutor, Maths is a difficult subject for
>   the most and studying it by yourself can be a bit hard, here in our
>   channel we focus on helping you learn the subject faster and from an
>   exam point of view.
>
> We guarantee that you can go through the entire syllabus in under
>   12 hours. We will have syllabus targeted for different universities in
>   later stages and for now, we are starting with *University_Name*
>
> So if you are thinking you will not pass the coming exam, now think
>   again isn't it too soon to lose hope?

English is not my first language and this is an introduction that I wrote for the channel.Is there anyway website or discussion forum where I can get peer reviews or get suggestions on making it more expressive and precise

Comment: @Andrew Leach any help

Comment: Sachin please see the duplicate. That question lists the services we know of. If you find a better one, please do add another answer there.